# Having trouble with php login page

Tags: php, sql, authentication

I am newbie to php and I was just building simple login page with php here is my code:

```
<?php 
    $username=$_POST['uname'];
    $password=$_POST['pass'];
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","myblog");
    $sql="SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
        echo "login successful";
    } else {
        echo "login failed";
    }
?>
```

The problem is I am getting "login successful" message even with the wrong credentials(random inputs).
Please someone guide me.

Comment: Please, please, please, please, please **learn about SQL injection**! Escape your inputs.

Comment: the answer lies with your query result and that is what you lack

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to check if query was succesfull, but if result has some rows..

```
$answer = mysqli_query($con,$sql)
if(  mysqli_num_rows($answer)>0   ) {  ... there is such record...   }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <?php
include "connect.php";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

$email    = filter_var( $_POST['email'] , FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL) ;
$password =  $_POST['password'] ;
$token = $_POST['token'] ;

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?") ;
$stmt->execute(array($email , $password));

$user = $stmt->fetch() ;

$row = $stmt->rowcount()  ;

if ($row > 0) {

    $id        = $user['id'] ;
    $stmt2 = $con->prepare("UPDATE users SET token = ? WHERE id = ? ") ;
    $stmt2->execute(array($token , $id )) ;


    $  username  = $user['username'] ;
    $email     = $user['email'] ;
    $password  = $user['password'] ;
 echo json_encode(array('id' => $id , 'username' => $username ,'email' => 
    $email ,'password' => $password , 'status' => "success"));
      }else {
 echo json_encode (array('status' => "faild" , 'email' => $email  , 
       'password' => $password) );
     }


    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

try this

you have to check whether result produced or not ... Instead of query correct or not..

```
<?php 
$username=$_POST['uname'];
$password=$_POST['pass'];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","myblog");
$sql="SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";

$result =mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count>0)
{
echo "login successful";
}
else
{
echo "login failed";
}
?>
```

Comment: Because you didn't make any mention of the need to escape the `$_POST` values.

Answer (score -1):

Try to do it like this. use `mysqli_num_rows()`

```
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >0){
       echo "login successful";
    }else {
       echo "login failed";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<?php 
    $username=$_POST['uname'];
    $password=$_POST['pass'];
    
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($username));
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($password));
    
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","myblog");
    $sql="SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1 ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        echo "login successful";
    }   
    else 
    {
        echo "login failed";
    }
?>
```

Your Condition is not proper, also use `LIMIT 1` whenever you trying to fetch exact one result.

You should pass your post variable through `mysql_real_escape_string` and `stripslashes` to prevent from sql injections